# google cloud store access locally from eclipse and appengine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I setup eclipse for Google Appengine. I am trying to upload image to google cloud store. When i run locally, it works. However I do not know how to access the image in local environment(supposed to be GCS).

I am uploading to app store using below code

```
outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsfileName, instance);
outputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel);
byte[] buffer = new byte[GCS_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
while(bytesRead != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
 }
} catch(IOException e) {
     log.severe(method+"IOException occured["+e.getMessage()+"]");
}
```